# Multiple dropdown navigation - how to change the trigger button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling with one of my dropdowns.

Currently it is set up to be triggered by an i tag to drop down the sub menu.

```
$('nav li i').click(function() {
```

I want to change it to (nav li a) so it is not the icon that has to be pressed

I also have the code:

```
var child = $(this).index('nav ul li i');
```

but i am not sure what to change this to?

You can see all the code in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/VNYAx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I do not see the `<a>` element anywhere, I have changed the `<i>` to `<a>` for demonstration purposes. You can see the example on http://jsfiddle.net/VNYAx/3/

Basically I changed

```
$('nav li i').click(function() {
```

to

```
$('nav li a').click(function() {
```

And also

```
var child = $(this).index('nav ul li i');
```

to

```
var child = $(this).index('nav ul li a');
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes that works! I thought I had tried that and it didn't work. Clearly I hadn't done it correctly

Comment: Also. what is the .index('nav ul li a'); for?

I also tried it with .index(); before you answered and it worked but is this the right thing to do?

Comment: `child` is used to determine which menu to show. If you click first `<a>` element, you open first menu, second `<a>` second menu, etc.

Comment: If i want to use a tags in the sub li's what would I change the index to?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the index of the icon as a way to identify which dropdown you want to slide down, you can save a reference to that dropdown by searching for '.dropdown' within the element clicked.

```
$('nav li').click(function () {
    var $childDropdown = $(this).find('.dropdown');

    if ($childDropdown.is(':visible')) {
        $('.dropdown').slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $('.dropdown').slideUp(300);
        $childDropdown.slideDown(300);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Fk7j/2/

Comment: that does look easy. Only problem is I want the dropdown to drop down right underneath each button

Comment: ahh sorry I think it is working I was looking at the wrong one! I think find will be easier!!

Comment: find can also be faster in some cases.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative approach to this problem using [`.slideToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/). If you need anything explaining please comment and I will edit the answer. I have commented the JavaScript below. I also removed the extra `<div>` in the markup as the nested `<ul>` is a perfectly good container.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sc3DV/)

**HTML**

```
<nav id="moo">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 7</li>
                <li>Item 8</li>
                <li>Item 9</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
nav li {
    position: relative;
}
ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $allSubMenus = $('ul ul');                // handle to all submenus

$('nav li a').click(function (e) {
    var $li = $(this).closest('li');          // get parent <li> of the <a> clicked on
    var $subMenu = $li.find('ul');            // get our submenu
    $allSubMenus.not($subMenu).slideUp(300);  // hide all other submenus
    $subMenu.slideToggle(300);                // show our submenu
    e.stopPropagation();                      // stop event bubbling further
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $allSubMenus.hide();                      // no need to reselect, just use handle
});
```